# No bootstrap code works after my header/nav?

Tags: html, css

All the code work so far but whenever i try and input bootstrap elements after the header its not displaying properly? Anyone know what going on here? Not sure why because the code all works so far? Anything after the header-main div is not displaying correctly!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>The Beckwood - Scunthorpe</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" 
    rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=satisfy" 
    rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy" 
    rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">


    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="header-main">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" >
                         <img src="assets/img/logo.png">

                    </a>
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#">MENU</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">BOOK A TABLE</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="hero">
                <h1 id="welcome">Welcome to The Beckwood.</h1>
                <p>The Beckwood is a family run pub located in scunthorpe offering quality homemade food, carverys, events and live sports.</p>
                <div class="btn btn-primary">View Menu</div>
                <div class="btn btn-primary">Book a table</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: check for bootstrap doc to see if you follow the HTML DOM required. Else, also check your own style.css, sometimes it overwrite the bootstrap.css

Comment: Open browser console, is there some errors ?

Comment: Stupid question perhaps, but in your example code there is nothing after the header-main div. Everything is inside it.

Comment: (If the indenting is correct, you have an extraneous `</div>` - just where you report the problems starting.)

Comment: Hi Mr Lister, yes ive removed everything. Even if i paste a standard bootstrap grid it wont work properly :/ is there anyway i can show my css file to see if thats whats causing it?

Comment: i have removed the extra </div> but it still doing the same. Can't get the grid to work for the life of me! anyway i can copy my css file to see if thats the problem?

Comment: can you elaborate on what "elements" do not work? I've copy/pasted your code as-is (w/o the trailing </div>) and the grid system to behaves.